# Inequality in sum of fractions

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

> Is there a constant $C\ge 0$ such that for any $a,b,c,d>0$ the inequality holds:
>   $$
> \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a} \ge C+\frac{a+b}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{c+d}+\frac{c+d}{d+a}
> $$

---

My attempt:

$a=b=c=d$ gives $1\ge C$.

Now, take $b=c=d$; this leads to inequality with two variables ($a$ and, let's say, $b$), which for $C=1$ is equivalent to $a^3+2b^3\ge 3ab^2$. This one is true by Cauchy.

The case $a=b$, $c=d$ leads to the same thing.

Is $C=1$ good?

Comment: $a,b,c,d>0$ - this assumption is in the post from the beginning

Comment: Are they real numbers?

Comment: yes, positive reals

Comment: Indeed, since the inequality is scale invariant, it does not matter if the constants are assumed to be integers or not.

Comment: @GregoryGrant more important is that the title doesn't reflect the content of the problem. Updated.

Comment: @Joffan That's true, I was stuck on stucked

Comment: Since the inequality is $... \geq C + ...$ with $C \geq 0$, wouldn't it be possible to just take $C=0$, and just consider the inequality without the $C$? Or is the idea to look for the biggest $C$ possible?

Comment: I'm not even sure (i.e. I have no proof) $C=0$ works fine! However, taking random four numbers in the computer many times, showed no counterexample for $C=1$. And some general cases (listed in the post) also turned out to be true with $C=1$. So the problem is: does $C=1$ work always; if not, does any $C\ge 0$ work.

Answer (score 3):

Using scaling of  $a,b,c,d$ you can set $d=1$ without loss of generality.

This gives the function
$$
f(a,b,c) \equiv \left( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + c + \frac{1}{a} \right) - \left( \frac{a+b}{b+c} + \frac{b+c}{c+1} + \frac{c+1}{1+a}\right)
$$
to minimize.

Taking the derivative $\frac{\partial f(a,b,c)}{\partial b}$ gives a result that is linear in $a$, hence equating to zero gives that for the extremum one gets 
$$
a = \frac{b^2(b^2 + 2 b c -c^3)}{c^2 (1+c) (2 b +c)}
$$
After that it becomes rather messy.

It is of course cheating but a numerical minimisation of the function $f(a,b,c)$ gives that the minimum is obtained for $a \approx 1.193389$, $b \approx 2.201712$, $c \approx 1.494538$ and results in $C \approx 0.810126$.

Comment: That's a wicked answer, and it taught me something new. I myself wouldn't have thought to invoke the “scaling . . . without loss of generality” argument. For that, +1 :)

Comment: Is there a way to solve this problem *without* invoking that argument?

Comment: You don't need to use the scaling, it simply means that the set of values $(fa,fb,fc,fd)$for any value of $f>0$ gives the same results for the fractions on the left and right hand side. In a numerical approach it becomes important because any solution is automatically an infinite set of solutions which results in problems that better should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks guys! Now the problem is how to prove (without computer approximations) the inequality at least with $C=0$ (the best $C$, if it's not $1$, will probably be a nasty irrational, so now no sense looking for it).

Answer (score 2):

For $C=1$ it's wrong. Try $a=10$, $b=15$, $c=10$ and $d=11$.